# Failed Castle ActiveRecord TransactionScope causes future queries to be invalid

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord, transactionscope

I am trying to solve an issue when using a Castle ActiveRecord TransactionScope which is rolled back.

After the rollback, I am unable to query the Dog table. The "Dog.FindFirst()" line fails with "Could not perform SlicedFindAll for Dog", because it cannot insert dogMissingName.

```
using (new SessionScope())
{
    try
    {
        var trans = new TransactionScope(TransactionMode.New, OnDispose.Commit);

        try 
        {
             var dog = new Dog
             {
                 Name = "Snowy"
             };
             dog.Save();
             var dogMissingName = new Dog();
             dogMissingName.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           trans.VoteRollBack();
           throw;
        }
        finally
        {
           trans.Dispose();
        }   
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         var dogFromDatabase = Dog.FindFirst();
         Console.WriteLine("A dog: " + dogFromDatabase.Name);
     }
 }
```

Stacktrace is as follows:

```
Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.ActiveRecordException: Could not perform SlicedFindAll for Dog ---> NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert: [Mvno.Dal.Dog#219e86fa-1081-490a-92d1-9d480171fcfd][SQL: INSERT INTO Dog (Name, Id) VALUES (?, ?)] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Name', table 'Dog'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   ved System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   ved NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)
   ved NHibernate.AdoNet.NonBatchingBatcher.AddToBatch(IExpectation expectation)
   ved NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   ved NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   ved NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   ved NHibernate.Action.EntityInsertAction.Execute()
   ved NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
   ved NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
   ved NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
   ved NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
   ved NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.OnAutoFlush(AutoFlushEvent event)
   ved NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.AutoFlushIfRequired(ISet`1 querySpaces)
   ved NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria, IList results)
   ved NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results)
   ved NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List()
   ved Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.SlicedFindAll(Type targetType, Int32 firstResult, Int32 maxResults, Order[] orders, ICriterion[] criteria)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   ved Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.SlicedFindAll(Type targetType, Int32 firstResult, Int32 maxResults, Order[] orders, ICriterion[] criteria)
   ved Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.FindFirst(Type targetType, Order[] orders, ICriterion[] criteria)
   ved Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.FindFirst(Type targetType, ICriterion[] criteria)
   ved Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase`1.FindFirst(ICriterion[] criteria)
```

Comment: please post the full stack trace

Comment: Note that if I replace the outer SessionScope with TransactionScope, it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **look at the stack trace**, you'll realize that the invalid `dogMissingName` record is still hanging around in the session's batched insertion buffer, even after the first attempt to perform the insertion failed.  Calling `Dog.FindFirst()` later in the same session **re-triggers an internal `Flush()`** (which attempts once again the failed insert.)

From [section 9.6](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-9/1nr4enxv3dpeq/12#9(2E)7(2E)2(2E)(C2)(A0)Committing_the_database_transaction) of the documentation:

> From time to time the ISession will
>   execute the SQL statements needed to
>   synchronize the ADO.NET connection's
>   state with the state of objects held
>   in memory. This process, flush, occurs
>   by default at the following points
>
> - from some invocations of Find() or Enumerable()
> - from NHibernate.ITransaction.Commit()
> - from ISession.Flush()

Additionally, from [section 9.7.2](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-9/1nr4enxv3dpeq/12#9(2E)7(2E)2(2E)(C2)(A0)Committing_the_database_transaction) of the documentation:

> If you rollback the transaction you should immediately close and discard the current session
>   to ensure that NHibernate's internal state is consistent.

Simply **moving `using (new SessionScope())` *inside* the outermost `try`/`catch`** may be a viable workaround (the initial insertion will fail, raise an exception which will take you out of the `SessionScope`, likely triggering a second failure on the same insert, failure which you finally `catch` -- also see ["data is not flushed on SessionScope.Flush()"](http://markmail.org/message/5qh4uiqemxq56dbz) in `com.googlegroups.castle-project-users`.).

Alternatively, if you don't want to close the session, you should be able to **simply [change the session default flush behaviour](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-9/1nr4enxv3dpeq/12#9(2E)6(2E)(C2)(A0)Flush)** (see the `FlushMode` class) so that it never flushes unless `Flush()` is called explicitly (e.g. before committing.)  Note that managing flushing in this way **will get complex and error-prone very quickly**, though.

Answer (score 2):

The key is right on Vlad's answer:

> If you rollback the transaction you
>   should immediately close and discard
>   the current session to ensure that
>   NHibernate's internal state is
>   consistent.

After you understand and apply that, your code should then look like this:

```
try
{
    using (new SessionScope())
    using (var trans = new TransactionScope(TransactionMode.New, OnDispose.Commit))
    {
        try 
        {
            var dog = new Dog { Name = "Snowy" };
            dog.Save();
            var dogMissingName = new Dog();
            dogMissingName.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            trans.VoteRollBack();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    using (new SessionScope())
    {
        var dogFromDatabase = Dog.FindFirst();
        Console.WriteLine("A dog: " + dogFromDatabase.Name);
    }
}
```